# Program to get change (rounding help)

Tags: java, rounding

I am trying to round the number of nickels in my program (there are no pennies anymore). So if I input 1.44 it should round to 1.40 and if I had 1.46 it should round to 1.50. Please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MakingChange
{

    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double amount = 0;
        while (true) {
             try {
                 amount = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                 break; // will only get to here if input was a double
             } catch (NumberFormatException ignore)   {
                 System.out.println("INVALID\r\n$");
             }
         }

        //calculating amount of change in cents 
        int remainingAmount = (int)(amount * 100.00);
        //toonies
        int numberofToonies =   (int) (remainingAmount / 200.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 200;
        //loonies   
        int numberofLoonies = (int) (remainingAmount / 100.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 100;
        //quarters
        int numberofQuarters = (int)(remainingAmount / 25.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 25;
        //dimes      
        int numberofDimes = (int)(remainingAmount / 10.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 10;
        //nickels  
        int numberofNickels = (int)(remainingAmount / 5.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 5;
        //rounded value
       numberofNickels=(int) (((amount -(numberofToonies * 2) - (numberofLoonies *1) - (numberofQuarters *0.25) - (numberofDimes * 0.10) - (numberofNickels * 0.05))+0.04)/0.05);

System.out.println(".*toonies:" + numberofToonies + ";" + " loonies:" + numberofLoonies + ";" + " quarters:" + numberofQuarters + ";" + " dimes:" + numberofDimes + ";" + " nickels:" + numberofNickels +"$" );


        }

}
```

Comment: So exactly how is this code not working?

Comment: *you can do it US style, if you have 1.44, then you get 1 and the tips jar gets .44 :p* Maybe you are looking for [`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-). Also note that you should not use double for monetary stuff (use `BigDecimal` for example)

Comment: Well instead of giving me two nickels, it'll only give me one...the rounding is off. Also when i do get two nickels, I want it to show 1 dime and not two nickels

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to multiply the number by ten, round it with [Math.round()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)), then divide it back by ten.

```
1.46 * 10 = 14.6
Math.round(14.6) = 15
15 / 10 = 1.5

1.44 * 10 = 14.4
Math.round(14.4) = 14
14 / 10 = 1.4
```

This can be implemented by the following lambda :

```
d -> Math.round(d * 10) / 10.0
```

Specifying `10.0` instead of `10` is important since `Math.round()` returns a `long` value and you don't want integer divison but float division.

You can see it in action on [this ideone snippet](https://ideone.com/z6rt60).

Comment: Writing that logic into a reusable helper method would be a good idea, e.g. `double roundToNickel(double amount)`.

Comment: @Aaron, could you send me a snippet of the code?  I am unsure as to how it would look like. Also, why wouldn't I simply multiply it by 0.05 and then divide by 0.05

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to ask user for his input

```
public class MakingChange
{
    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert amount:");
        double amount = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                amount = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                break; // will only get to here if input was a double
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                System.out.println("INVALID\r\n$");
            }
        }

        // calculating amount of change in cents
        int remainingAmount = (int) (amount * 100.00);
        // toonies
        int numberofToonies = (int) (remainingAmount / 200.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 200;
        // loonies
        int numberofLoonies = (int) (remainingAmount / 100.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 100;
        // quarters
        int numberofQuarters = (int) (remainingAmount / 25.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 25;
        // dimes
        int numberofDimes = (int) (remainingAmount / 10.00);
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 10;

        // nickels
        int numberofNickels = 0;
        // if the remaining amount is exactly 5 cents
        if (remainingAmount == 5) {
            numberofNickels = 1;
        } else if (remainingAmount > 5)// round to higher value if remaining
                                        // value is greater than 5 cents e.g
                                        // 20.68
        {
            numberofDimes += 1;
        }

        System.out.println(".*toonies:" + numberofToonies + ";" + " loonies:" + numberofLoonies + ";" + " quarters:"
                + numberofQuarters + ";" + " dimes:" + numberofDimes + ";" + " nickels:" + numberofNickels + "$");

    }
}
```